# How to make adaptive responsive flexible header with CSS Grid and/or/without Flexbox?

Tags: css, css-grid

Ok, so my header module has a logo, a phone component and a basket component. Here's that header:
[image]

And here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Adaptive responsive header, so it look nicely on 400-1920px viewport widths.
2. To be able to reorder all header components in any order.
3. When viewport width is bigger than 640px I want logo be on the left side, phone and basket modules to be on the right side, as on the image above.
4. When viewport width is 480-640px I want phone and basket components both to be on the second row and I want distances from their edges to outer borders to be the same, like this:

[image]

4. When viewport width is smaller than 480px by default I want logo be on the first row, phone on the second row and basket on the third row, like this:

[image]

5. But I want to be able to swap logo and phone component without editing html, to make it to look like this:

[image]

I can't make it so it meets all the requirements. Here's the best I came up with so far:
https://next.plnkr.co/edit/9nHCyGk2KC8ZO9JA?preview

I can swap phone and basket, but not phone and logo and not basket and logo. If I remove `<div class="pg-Header_phoneBasketContainer">` element from html and apply `grid-area: phone` and `grid-area: basket` directly on phone and basket accordingly, then I can't make same distances from phone and basket edges to outer borders be the same, because there will be 2 cells in a second row and it will position grid items relatively to their cells, and these items aren't the same length, so distance to the borders will be different.

If I could use grid-positioning on indirect children of a grid container, then it would be easily done with grid areas. I would just define appropriate `grid-template-areas` for a container and appropriate `grid-area` properties for `.pg-Header_phoneBasketContainer`, `.pg-Header_phone` and `.hdr-Basket` in different viewports:
[image]

```
.hdr-Top {
display: grid;
grid-template-areas: "logo phoneBasket";

}
.pg-Header_logo {
    grid-area: logo;
}
.pg-Header_phoneBasketContainer {
    grid-area: phoneBasket;
}

@media only screen and(max-width: 480px) {
    .hdr-Top {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: "phone" "logo" "basket";
    }
    .pg-Header_phone {
        grid-area: phone;
    }
    .hdr-Basket {
        grid-area: basket;
    }
}
```

It would result in this on bigger screens:
[image]

And this on smaller:

[image]

Unfortunately, [CSS Grid doesn't allow grid positioning of indirect children](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/313). Any ideas how I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot divide `phoneBasket` and put `logo` in the middle for small screens - but you can achieve what you want by having 1 container with 3 children.

With this you can reorder grid-items using `grid-template-areas` property:

```css
.header {
  padding: .25rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "logo phone basket";
  align-items: center;
  grid-gap: .5rem;
}

.header-item {
  padding: .5rem;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.logo {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.phone {
  grid-area: phone;
}

.basket {
  border: 2px solid #999;
  grid-area: basket;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
  .header {
    grid-template-areas: "logo logo" "phone basket";
    grid-template-columns: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .header {
    grid-template-areas: "phone" "logo" "basket";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-item logo">MyCompany</div>
  <div class="header-item phone">555-3535</div>
  <div class="header-item basket">3 items</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried using `grid-template-areas: "phone" "logo" "basket";` with `justify-content: center;` but it didn't work. Now when you answered I tried it again, and it (of course) worked, just like on your example. Obviously, I made a mistake when I tried it earlier by myself. Many thanks for help.